# JTable binding Avoiding Default Value

Tags: java, swing, data-binding, jtable

I am using Java beans binding to bind Jtable and in which api gives the default values for integer or float values such as 0 or 0.0 as shown below.I would like to avoid the corresponding default values and set the cells as empty except last cell value.

```
1        WW     88.0        88.0      1021021       340.0       
4        TT     55.0        55.0      1021021       340.0       
5        PP     66.0        66.0      1021021       340.0

                0            0          0           1020

2        gg     66.0        66.0      1021022       320.0       
3        LL     658.0       652.0     1021022       320.0

               0            0          0             640
```

and the table should looks like ..

```
1        WW     88.0        88.0      1021021       340.0       
4        TT     55.0        55.0      1021021       340.0       
5        PP     66.0        66.0      1021021       340.0

                                                    1020

2        gg     66.0        66.0      1021022       320.0       
3        LL     658.0       652.0     1021022       320.0

                                                     640
```

any one who can suggest the better way to solve this problem, it will be great full and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using Jtable beans binding and using beansbinding-1.2.1.jar api for auto binding.  I downloaded the beansbinding-1.2.1.jar source and make relevant changes in the class

/org.jdesktop.swingbinding.JTableBinding.java

```
containing the class BindingTableModel.java which implements the TableModel and I overridden the method as per the suggestions of above two friends and thanks to all...
```

@Override

```
public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
            Object value = valueAt(row, column);

            if (value != null
                    && (value.toString().equals("0") || value.toString()
                            .equals("0.0")|| value.toString().equals("default"))) {
                return null;
            }

            return value;
        }
```

Comment: I don't think that's the way you want to go... I would recommend extending the BindingTableModel where you are using it - otherwise you are insisting that any other cases where you might want to use BindingTableModel will also get this behaviour. Generally speaking, it's usually a bad idea to go and change the source of a 3rd party jar. (Also, again, it's good practice to accept answers...)

Comment: Hei,   private final class BindingTableModel extends ListBindingManager implements TableModel . is the Structure of BidingTableModel inside JTableBinding ,then how it be possible to extend the BindingTableModel class.?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest this should be done in the `TableModel`, in particular using the `getValueAt(int row, int column)` method. Something like:

```
public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex){
  Object cellValue = // get your values out of your Beans...
  if (cellValue==0 && columnIndex!=LAST_COLUMN_INDEX){
    return null;
  }
  return cellValue;
}
```

Comment: The only problem with this solution is the default values from the API will cease to exist as it will be overridden by null, even at places where the default value is required.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the first column is blank for this problem statement

You can override the `TableModel` `getValueAt(int row, int column)` method.

```
@Override
public Object getValueAt(int row, int column){
  Object value = super.getValueAt(row, column);//Or get it from the Vector defined
  if(column == 2) {//Demo for the third column do same for other columns
    //Check the value in the first column if it is coming null
    if (null == getValueAt(row, 0) || getValueAt(row, 0) == ""){
      return null; // null means blank cell
    }
  }
  return value;
}
```